# Use Mule ESB to Bridge two two-way web services into one

Tags: mule, esb

I need to Mule to bridge one web services on the one side (1) with two asynchronous web services on the other side(2). Server can take anywhere from under a second to tens of minutes to process a request. Web Service (1) will hang and not return until webservice 3 returns with its result.

Server is handling each request asynchronously  - so if I send request that takes minute to process and after that another request that takes just a second, I will receive result of the second request before the first one. Mule needs to work in the same way and process every request ASAP.

Task ID is randomly generated by the server and client of web service (1) doesn't know anything about it.

I am not very skilled in Mule - but i know to do some simple flows. Here I don't even now where to start.

[image: graph]

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the request-reply processor: 
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-RequestReply

Comment: Thanks for a hint. I still haven't figured out how to use it to implement what I wan't.

I would be thankful if you would direct me how to construct flows taking into account that I need to match TACK_ID.

Comment: Or if you could just point me to similar uses of request-reply processor. The use case on Mule documentation site doesn't seam to be similar to what I need.